# Functions carry over from modules...why don't variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Say you define a function (def func) and a variable (var = ) in a module.

When you import that module to your main.py, the function carries over (ie is able to be used) but the variable does not carry over (ie you have to reassign the var in main.py in order to use it in main.py).

Is there a reason why this happens? and is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you show what you mean in code? Modules treat functions and variables in much the same way.

Comment: Actually in Python `def func` creates a variable called `func`, referring to a function object.

Comment: If you are importing the module you have to specify what you are importing, using `from module import foo, bar` or you can import the whole module using `import module` and access the var/functions with `module.foo += 1` and `module.bar(module.foo)`. You can also import everthing from a module to the current namespace using `from module import *` but that's not advisable.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that only a module's functions are accessible after importing, but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

All Functions AND variables in module scope will be imported. If the variable is initialized or assigned to inside a function, you may not see that value until that function has been executed. To make sure you get the most current value of the variable, you may have to use `module_name.variable_name` rather than just `variable_name`.

Let us say you have two source files t1.py and t2.py

`t1.py`

```
v1 = 10

def f1():
    global v1
    v1 = 11
```

`t2.py`

```
from t1 import f1, v1

f1()
print(v1)
```

If you run t2.py you will still see 10. But if you change t2.py as follows:

```
import t1

t1.f1()
print(t1.v1)
```

You will see 11.

There is an added twist. If v1 were a list or dictionary (or object), you don't need the additional `module_name` qualifier. They are accessed *by reference* so you will see the value even without it.